# Django AllAuth gives SSLError

Tags: python, django, ssl, oauth-2.0

I am trying to use AllAuth to authenticate into different sites. I tried for both Google and Facebook now, and I am getting the same error for both after successfully logging into the sites:

```
SSLError at /allauth/google/login/callback/
[Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:340: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
```

Can somebody help me further?
Thanks and best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out the ca_certs was missing. The problem is fixed by replacing

```
client = httplib2.Http()
```

in line 42 and 52 of allauth/socialaccount/requests.py with

```
client = httplib2.Http(ca_certs=PATH_TO_YOUR_CERT_FILE)
```

The CERT_FILE would be the cacert.pem file in the certifi (can be installed via pip or macports, etc.) module.

Seems to be an ugly hack, hope for better solutions.

Comment: There is no `requests.py` in `socialaccount` folder. What to do now ?